# Why this error occurred: cannot return value referencing local variable `v`

Tags: rust

```rust
match base64::decode(text) {
    Ok(v) => str::from_utf8(&v).ok(),
    _ => None
}
```

With this program, the following error occurs.
I would like someone to explain what this means and what should I do.

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `v`
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
`v` is borrowed here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`base64::decode` documentation](https://docs.rs/base64/0.13.0/base64/fn.decode.html), its signature looks like this:

```rust
pub fn decode<T: AsRef<[u8]>>(input: T) -> Result<Vec<u8>, DecodeError>
```

Your input is taken as reference `&[u8]`. The output of the function is an owned type `Result<Vec<u8>, DecodeError>`. So far so good.

You **move** the result of `base64::decode(text)` function into the `match` expression. In the `Ok` branch, you **move** the `Vec<u8>` into `v` variable. Understand, that now the **owner** of decoded `Vec<u8>` is `v`. Inside this branch, you borrow the vector using `&v`. However [`str::from_utf8` function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) has a signature:

```
pub fn from_utf8(v: &[u8]) -> Result<&str, Utf8Error>
```

Meaning that the return value of it is not owned, it still borrows the input value. By doing

```
Ok(v) => str::from_utf8(&v).ok()
```

you try to return this borrowed value, however remember that the **owner** of `Vec<u8>` is `v`. After `match` expression is finished, the owner `v` is destroyed, the data of `Vec<u8>` is destroyed.

The error you get notifies you, that `match` tries to return borrowed data, that will no longer be valid after `match` is finished.

---

The easiest way to fix it is to use `String` type, instead of `&str` type like this:

```
let decoded = match base64::decode("aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=") {
    Ok(v) => String::from_utf8(v).ok(),
    _ => None
};
println!("{:?}", decoded);
// Some("hello world")
```

Hopefully you won't waste any memory, because [in documentation of `String::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) it's said that

> This method will take care to not copy the vector, for efficiency’s sake.